# Test assertion failed on matched value

Tags: c#, assert

I have this test method failed even if debugger show correct value. Why this test is not passing then?

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Should_60Deegrees_ForArcCosOfHalf()
    {
        var deegrees = (Math.Acos(0.5) * 180 / Math.PI);
        Assert.AreEqual(60, deegrees);
    }
```

Comment: Probably because of floating-point arithmetic. You should not compare doubles via equality but with a tolerance. Btw.: what are you testing here?

Comment: Thanks! Math.Round method helps. This is for testing angle calculation using altitude and distance of gps paths.  I just removed objects from test method to explain the issue.